# ORA-06512: in "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536

Tags: oracle

Guys i have a problem with this error at ORACLE i think is permissions but i don't know where can i do something.
HELP!

```
ORA-20123: ERROR DMM_INTER_STOCK_SAP: ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: in "DMM.GEN_PKG_INTER" line 973
ORA-06512: online 2
The process has finished.


DIRECTORY_NAME  DIR_DEP_DMM_BK
DIRECTORY_PATH  /oracle/app/oracle/file/DEP/DMM/BK
Privilege list  EXECUTE, READ, WRITE
```

Comment: You should explain what you were doing. This is just some generic error, saying that you performed "invalid operation" on some file. What is GEN_PKG_INTER containing at line #973?

Answer (score 0):

```
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
```

means you got the error during an FOPEN call. You need to ensure that the OS and the database are "in alignment" in terms of permissions.

The *database* privs you have listed indicate you can read/write the directory *object*. But you also need to check the OS directory /oracle/app/oracle/file/DEP/DMM/BK that it (a) exists, and (b) can be written to by the database OS account (typically 'oracle').